# update Cassandra row according to value comparison

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I need to update row in Cassandra table  if the value greater than the stored value  or not can I make this process on one transaction or I must select first to compare ?!

Comment: `"if the value greater than the stored value or not"`... What do you mean? What do you do if the value is not greater? Skip the update?

Comment: yes I'll skip the update if the value not greater

Comment: Then just use conditional updates as proposed below. You can find the documentation here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html#cqlUpdate__conditionally-updating-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPDATE IF [condition]` ,but note that it is LWT transaction and has high latency and should be avoided if not rarely used.

Comment: what about UDF can I make using it ?!